# "The import [...] conflicts with a type defined in the same file" error [java]

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm importing a package (in my case, mongodb.DB) into a java file with an identically named class.

In python, I know I can import a module as another name to avoid conflicts.  How does Java solve this problem?

It's not feasible to change the name of the class I'm working in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you are "importing a package..." - do you mean you are importing all classes in a package, like "a.b.c.*"?  If so, the answer might be to import only those classes you need, not the entire package.

There is no way to import a class as another class.

Hopefully you don't really mean "identically named" as in both of them having the same fully-qualified name.  If that's the case, you're screwed, I don't know anything you can do.  Hopefully you just mean that the class name is the same in two different packages.

You can extend a class with your own class, and use your new class in the place of the one extended.  In other words, if you're importing the class D as in a.b.c.D, and there is another D class, you could extend the first of them (class Z extends a.b.c.D), and then refer to it as Z instead of D. You might need to provide constructors for Z that match ones in D, but no code should be required other than that.

And the fully-qualified names of the classes will always work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fully qualified name "mongodb.DB" instead of just the class name.